# Build phone number regex filter

Tags: php, regex

I need to make phone number filter using reg ex.

here is my code

```
<?php
$LIST =['1234123', '0121234123', '123-1234', '1234-123','0123-123-1234',
'123 4123', '012a1234123', '123x1234', '12341-23', '012-3123-1234'];
$regex = '/(\d{3}-\d{4}$)|(\d{4}-\d{3}$)|(\d{3,4}-\d{3}-\d{4}$)|(\d{3,4}-\d{4}-\d{3}$)|(^[0-9]{7,10}$)/';

foreach ($LIST as $key => $value) 
{
    echo $value.">>".(preg_match($regex, $value)).'<br/>';
}
?>
```

and here is the results

```
1234123>>1
0121234123>>1
123-1234>>1
1234-123>>1
0123-123-1234>>1
123 4123>>0
012a1234123>>0
123x1234>>0
12341-23>>0
012-3123-1234>>1
```

What makes me confused is the last one.
I want to make the last want will give 0 result while maintain the rest result.

Comment: Regex might not be the best way to validate a phone number.  You can split the string and use core PHP in a much cleaner way.

Comment: can you show me how?also how to code them?

Comment: Please ask a new question and make sure you show some effort on your part.  You will get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with phone numbers is not that easy. The phone numbers may be different from country to country, from one operator to another, etc.

Instead of using an regex let me recommend you to use a library for phone numbers: [libphonenumber-for-php](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php).

> The library can be used for parsing, formatting, storing and validating international phone numbers. This library is based on [Google's libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber).